# Short messages service center queue and retry

Tags: sms, telecommunication

I've searched a lot for the design of the sms queue and the retry scheme of the SMSC and it looks like it's a secret :), nothing in Google ever mentioned about it.

Anyone knows how it works and how to design it? I'm looking for the methods and data structures used to make one.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to different vendors and operators using totally different retry schemes. Keep in mind different vendors/platforms have different features and parameters implemented to handle their queues.

What exactly do you want to know?

I would start by reading the very few lines ETSI put up regarding SMS Retry (4.4 in TR 102 529 - V1.1.1) and relate that to the relevant specifications for SMS Delivery. Also, some vendors have put out general information about their parameters, eg. Symsoft and opensource Kannel/EasySMS.

Also find a patented retry algo from http://www.google.com/patents/US8055287.